# Windows 7 TCP Listen Ports

Tags: security, windows-7, tcpip

My fresh install of Windows 7 shows 5 programs listening on TCP ephermeral ports:

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:49157          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

netstat -ano shows that one of the processes is wininit.exe.

Why is wininit.exe listening for TCP traffic and how do I prevent it?  (I don't want to have to firewall it).

Answer (score 4):

Ports 135, 49152, 49153, 49154, 49155, 49156, & 49157 are all associated with MSRPC. You may want to try to turn it off in Services list.

Comment: No go.  You can't disable RPC without trashing windows.

Under Win2k3 these processes did not open TCP ports.

I'd like to disable them or bind them to the loopback address.  Anyone else have an answer?

Comment: If there's no way to disable it then i believe Microsoft has reasons for this. Maybe, they know better? ;)

Comment: It wasn't like this in previous versions of Windows.

I'd like to know why it is like this now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a local firewall installed, and through it saw a lot of strange ports open connected to a svchost.exe instance.  Disabling the IP Helper service got rid of them.

Comment: That answer is far too generic (and completely inapplicable to the specific ports in question anyway).